# C# equivalent of Java's Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()?

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception

Is there a C# equivalent of Java's `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's [`AppDomain.UnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) for non-WinForms, and [`Application.ThreadException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx) for WinForms.

They're unlikely to be *exactly* equivalent to the Java handler, but they may do what you need.

Comment: Noteworthy: "you'll get the standard .NET crash dialog in a console app, even if you've registered an unhandled exception handler for your AppDomain" http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000201.html

Comment: @dtb - Thanks, I just found that out. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The AppDomain.UnhandledException event.

Answer (score 0):

something like this ?

in your main method use this

```
Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
```

declare this

```
public static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    ... code goes here ...
}
```

That should handle any thread exceptions in a win-forms app, for console take a look at the AppDomain handler detailed by the poster above.